# Update Mysql with more than one edit

Tags: php, mysql, cron

So I run this php script as cron jobs updating points for users on scoreboard.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "UPDATE scoreboard SET points='23' WHERE id=2500";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

This works fine for only one `id` at a time. How can I edit 3 `id`'s with different points each? Thanks.

Comment: where id in (2500, 2501, 2502)

Comment: issue 3 updates. and note that `“` and `”` are not valid quote characters in mysql OR php. don't use a word processor to edit your code.

Comment: If you must.. you could `update scoreboard set points = case when ID = 2500 then '23' when Id = 'XXXX' then 'YY' when ID = 'YYYY' then 'XX' end where ID in (2500,'XXXX','YYYY')`  but single updates make more sense here; or you could write the a bulk insert to a table and update from that table if you have a serious number of records to update with different values.

Comment: @xQbert that did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must.. you could...

```
update scoreboard 
set points = case when ID = 2500 then '23' 
                  when Id = 'XXXX' then 'YY' 
                  when ID = 'YYYY' then 'XX' end 
where ID in (2500,'XXXX','YYYY')
```

But single updates make more sense here. You could write the a bulk insert to a temp table and update from that table if you have a thousands of records to update with different values.  This may be faster.

Answer (score 2):

You don't usually update 3 IDs per query in a list of users for a scoreboard. One request at a time works just fine and including 3 won't make it faster, unless these 3 players all have the same score, but you specifically mentioned you wanted 3 IDs with different scores for each.

If it's about performance/efficiency, use prepared statements ([mysqli's prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)) and use a loop after your `prepare()` in which you:

1. `bind()` the parameters (each time for a different user/points)
2. `execute()`